# executescalar returning null value

Tags: asp.net

```
 string checkuserQuery = "select username from usersign where Username=' " + TextBox1.Text + " ' ";
 SqlCommand usercom = new SqlCommand(checkuserQuery, conn);
 string user1 = string.Empty;
 Object val = usercom.ExecuteScalar();
 if (val != null)
 {
     user1 = val.ToString();
     if (user1 == TextBox1.Text)
     {

         string checkpasswordQuery = "select password from usersign     where Username=' " + TextBox1.Text + " ' ";
         SqlCommand passcom = new SqlCommand(checkpasswordQuery, conn);
         string password = passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
         if (password == TextBox2.Text)
         {
             Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
             Label5.Text = "password is correct";
             Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
         }
         else
         {
             Label5.Text = "password is not correct";

         }

     }
 }
 else
 {
     Label5.Text = "val is null";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Where is it "not working"? Can we have a decription of your problem please

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar()` will return null if the query doesn't return a value.

> Returns the first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This line will throw a null reference exception:

```
passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Building queries using string concatenation is error prone. More importantly, it is vulnerable to SQL injection. The code suggests that passwords are stored in the database in plain text.

**SQL injection and plain text passwords are a serious concern for *any* application. Parameterize your queries (it is very easy with ADO.Net) and hash your passwords.**

The lack of a match is probably caused by the following line:

```
string checkpasswordQuery = "select password from usersign     where Username=' " + TextBox1.Text + " ' ";
```

Note the extra spaces added in the string concatenation. Whatever is in `TextBox1` will be preceded/followed by whitespace, causing the match to fail.

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be the space characters in the following (i have put a * where space
is incorrectly used)

```
where Username='*" + TextBox1.Text + "*' "
```

So the above will mean that your query is trying to get a user name that has
a space character in start and at the end, so just remove those spaces

another point is, such query should be used with parameters as it is prone to
SQL injection type of attacks